# R-Select some rows with conditions

Tags: r

I have a data frame `t1` like this in R

```
name    age

Kevin   15
Lin     20
Kyte    8
```

I want to choose all rows in the first 2 rows and age >15. I try `t1[1:2 & age>15,]` but it doesn't work.

Really appreciate if someone can help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your data is in form of

```
t1<- data.frame(name=c("Kevin", "Lin", "Kyte"), age=c(15, 20, 8))
```

then try

```
 t1[1:nrow(t1)<=2 & t1$age>15,]
```

The vector `1:2` is shorter than `t1$age` (or just `age` if you have it as a variable), so when you compare them R would return a warning.

Comment: Or `t1[intersect(1:2, which(t1$age>15)),]`

Answer (score 0):

The way you are accesing the `age` column is wrong. Can you try the following:

```
t1[1:2 & t1$age>15,]
```

Hope this helps.